# Replace text inside xml tag with PHP

Tags: php, xml, replace, simplexml

I've been searching far and wide, but couldn't find exactly what I needed, so here I am.

I have a php script that uploads an xml file - no issue here.

With the uploaded file, I need to open it and replace text inside the tags.

Example below

```
<Styles>
    <Style p3:ID="Default" p3:Name="Normal" xmlns:p3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
      <p3:Font p3:FontName="Arial" p3:Size="10" />
      <p3:Alignment p3:Vertical="Top" p3:WrapText="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style p3:ID="Percent" p3:Name="Percent" xmlns:p3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
      <p3:NumberFormat p3:Format="0%" />
    </Style>
  </Styles>
```

Anywhere you see `p2` or `p3` I need to replace these with a different syntax `ss`.

I have php 7.3 installed which broke compatibility with a script I was using (https://pear.php.net/package/File_SearchReplace/redirected) which is no longer maintained unfortunately. Does anyone know either how to update this script or how to achieve the same result using `simpleXML` maybe?

Many thanks!

Comment: `p2` and `p3` are just namespace aliases/prefixes. If you need to replace them your reader does not use namespaces correctly. I suggest fixing the script that reads the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution. Algorithm for reading a file line by line and working with a string type. You can change the search pattern or method.

Maybe this will help

```
<?php

// faster replace word in file
function replaceWordInnerFile($pathToFile, $needleRegEx, $replace = null)
{
    if (!\is_file($pathToFile)) {
        throw new ErrorException('File not found');
    }

    if (!\is_writable($pathToFile)) {
        throw new ErrorException('File not writable');
    }

    $newFilePath = $pathToFile.'_new';

    $fileStream    = \fopen($pathToFile, 'r');
    $newFileStream = \fopen($pathToFile.'_new', 'w');  # create new file

    while ($row = \fgets($fileStream)) {
        // use any pattern for search
        if (!$replace) {
            // empty case
            \fwrite($newFileStream, \preg_replace("/\<p[0-9]+:NumberFormat p3:Format=\"${needleRegEx}\"\s+\/\>/", '', $row));
            continue;
        }
        \fwrite($newFileStream, \preg_replace("/\<p([0-9]+):NumberFormat p3:Format=\"${needleRegEx}\"\s+\/\>/", '<p${1}:NumberFormat p3:Format="'.$replace.'">', $row));
    }
    \fclose($fileStream);
    \fclose($newFileStream);

    \rename($pathToFile, $pathToFile.'.bak'); // backup original content
    \rename($newFilePath, $pathToFile);
}

replaceWordInnerFile('/tmp/file-name', '[0-9]+\%', '669977');
```

Result

```
<Styles>
    <Style p3:ID="Default" p3:Name="Normal" xmlns:p3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
      <p3:Font p3:FontName="Arial" p3:Size="10" />
      <p3:Alignment p3:Vertical="Top" p3:WrapText="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style p3:ID="Percent" p3:Name="Percent" xmlns:p3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
      <p3:NumberFormat p3:Format="669977">
    </Style>
  </Styles>
```

Docs:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace - Example #1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think I didn't make my point super clear. What I need to replace is the actual ```p2``` string, not its content.

Comment: @matteodallombra You can change patter search to `\preg_replace('/p(2|3):/', 'p33:', '<p3:NumberFormat p3:Format="669977">')`.